# Should we cast away [casting]?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

I feel that the [casting](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/casting) tag is not a very good tag for a few reasons:

1. It's too broad. Just a quick scan of the questions which use it show languages as varied as C++, Java, C#, SQL, Python, etc.
2. It has 0 followers, which indicates it's either not useful, or not interesting enough to follow.

I think [casting](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/casting) should be burned.

Comment: Casting and converting are different things. When you (type-)cast, the object still remains the same, you just treat it as a different type. With that said, I also don't see any reason for this tag.

Comment: @SimonForsberg Okay I rephrased my question to reflect this

Answer (score 6):

I'm not so sure.  Neither of those two reasons is a solid justification for eliminating a tag.

Applicability to multiple languages is a poor criterion.  By that logic, we should eliminate [fizzbuzz](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fizzbuzz).

[file](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/file) has 0 followers. [playing-cards](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/playing-cards) has just one follower.  I consider both of them to be useful categories.

Furthermore, there are questions about code whose primary purpose is casting.  For example: [A less verbose const_cast](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/102587/9357)

So, while we may want to re-evaluate how the tag is applied, I would hesitate to just blast it away.

Comment: I think that according to [my answer on other burninate-request](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/6545/should-we-put-scope-down-our-scope/6546#6546) [tag:casting] would fit into the 1st category even though it may be a subtle one.